# Is the Zariski topology the same as the cofinite topology?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $spec(R)$ be the set of all prime ideals on $R$. For any ideal $I$ on $R$, we define the $V_I$ to be the set of all prime ideals containing $I$. We define the Zariski topology on $spec(R)$ via the closed sets $\{V_I:I\textrm{ is an ideal of }R\}$.

I am still wrapping my mind around this topology. Can someone tell me if it is a cofinite topology, i.e. the open sets are complements of finite sets, or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can be infinite closed sets besides the whole space.

In $\Bbb Q[x,y]$, for example, $(y)$ is contained in infinitely many prime ideals, so $V_{(y)}$ is a closed, but not finite set.

Another way: the cofinite topology always makes its space [$T_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space), but the spectrum is $T_1$ in the Zariski topology iff prime ideals are maximal, and that only occurs for [certain rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/556087/29335).

Another way: The cofinite topology on a finite space is the discrete topology, but the Zariski topology on a ring with a finite spectrum need not be discrete. Consider, for example, $Spec(\Bbb Q[[x]])$, where the spectrum is $\{0, (x)\}$ and the closed sets are $\{\emptyset, \{x\}, \{0,(x)\}\}$

I've spent some time in the same boat as you on this topic. It's especially disorienting if most of your topological experience is derived from thinking about metrizable spaces.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is $F[x]$ for $F$ a field then yes they should be the same.  If $R=F[x,y]$ and $F$ is an infinite field then no, it's not the cofinite because it includes the complement of curves which are not finite.

Comment: They are not the same for $F[x]$. Every non-empty open set of the spectrum of $F[x]$ contains the zero ideal. So not all finite subsets are closed.

Comment: The maximal spectrum of $F[x]$ has the cofinite topology, but not the spectrum itself, as $(0)$ is a non-closed point.