# Prime ideals in ring of continuous functions

Tags: functions, ring-theory, continuity, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R:=C(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ be the ring of continuous $\mathbb R$-valued functions on $\mathbb R$. Is every prime ideal in $R$ maximal?

Comment: This is rather catastrophically false.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078755/finding-a-space-x-such-that-dim-cx-n for a general result which shows how badly this fails.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6):

No, because [that would imply](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/556087/29335) $J(R)$ is nil and $R/J(R)$ is von Neumann regular. (I am denoting the Jacobson radical of $R$ as $J(R)$.)

But it is easy to show in this ring that $J(R)$ is $\{0\}$ and $R$ is not von Neumann regular.  (In fact, this ring has only trivial idempotents, but there must be many idempotents in a von Neumann regular ring.)

You can read [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/527658/prime-ideals-in-c0-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) about the connection of prime ideals in this ring to ultrafilters. This is pretty much the best description you can get for prime ideals in such a ring, and it shows that in general prime ideals in a ring like this do not have to be maximal.

Comment: What is $J(R)$?

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain The Jacobson radical of $R$.